# Jolt to remove the slashes and extract the nested json

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have some problem when tried to used JOLT for modify JSON. We are getting data in a nested array and the json has some slashes/backslashes

I need to remove the slashes and extract the nested json "datatag" and load it into table using nifi

Input 1

```
[
  {
    "json": "\",\"datatag\":{\"Item\":\"000000000010000057\",\"Location\":\"NL01\",\"ERPGoodsReceiptTimeIL\":\"0\",\"ERPLotSizeIncrementIL\":\"0\",\"ERPMinLotsizeIL\":\"0.000\",\"ERPPlannedDeliveryTimeIL\":\"1\",\"ERPProcurementTypeInput\":\"F\",\"U_SPL_PROC_TYPE\":\"\",\"U_ERPReOrderPointQuantity\":\"0\",\"U_ERPTargetInventory\":\"0.000\",\"U_ERPDOSTarget\":\"00\",\"U_Purchasing_Group\":\"\",\"U_LGPRO\":\"9300\",\"U_LGFSB\":\"9300\",\"OperationType\":\"INSERT\",\"TimeStamp\":\"Mar 13 2024 3:00PM\"},\"endtag\":\""
  },
  {
    "json": "\",\"datatag\":{\"Item\":\"000000000010015005\",\"Location\":\"NL01\",\"ERPGoodsReceiptTimeIL\":\"10\",\"ERPLotSizeIncrementIL\":\"1\",\"ERPMinLotsizeIL\":\"8.000\",\"ERPPlannedDeliveryTimeIL\":\"5\",\"ERPProcurementTypeInput\":\"E\",\"U_SPL_PROC_TYPE\":\"\",\"U_ERPReOrderPointQuantity\":\"0\",\"U_ERPTargetInventory\":\"0.000\",\"U_ERPDOSTarget\":\"00\",\"U_Purchasing_Group\":\"101\",\"U_LGPRO\":\"1000\",\"U_LGFSB\":\"2000\",\"OperationType\":\"INSERT\",\"TimeStamp\":\"Mar 13 2024 3:00PM\"},\"endtag\":\""
  },
  {
    "json": "\",\"datatag\":{\"Item\":\"000000000010000108\",\"Location\":\"NL01\",\"ERPGoodsReceiptTimeIL\":\"0\",\"ERPLotSizeIncrementIL\":\"0\",\"ERPMinLotsizeIL\":\"0.000\",\"ERPPlannedDeliveryTimeIL\":\"1\",\"ERPProcurementTypeInput\":\"F\",\"U_SPL_PROC_TYPE\":\"\",\"U_ERPReOrderPointQuantity\":\"0\",\"U_ERPTargetInventory\":\"0.000\",\"U_ERPDOSTarget\":\"00\",\"U_Purchasing_Group\":\"\",\"U_LGPRO\":\"9300\",\"U_LGFSB\":\"9300\",\"OperationType\":\"INSERT\",\"TimeStamp\":\"Mar 13 2024 3:00PM\"},\"endtag\":\""
  }
]
```

Any help in Jolt spec is much appreciated

Comment: Hi Thiyagaraj, hope you're doing well. I think using `RerlaceText` processor,  which's suggested by @daggett , is a pretty better option as you're in Apache Ni-Fi platform. Using `JoltTransformJSON` would need lots of hardcoding if preferred.

Answer (score 1):

sounds you need `ReplaceText` with parameters:

- Search Value = `\\"`
- Replacement Value = `"`